# Synchronised data across all clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronized

A few weeks ago I watched a demo video of a framework that could synchronize data between clients. It showed 2 browsers that displayed a list of data. When a new item was inserted into one, it would also appear on the second.

I forgot to bookmark this website. I don't quite know the language it was written in, but I suspect node. Now I would like to investigate this mechanism of synchronizing data, but can't find this framework again.

Can anyone recall such a framework or comparable "technology"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably saw this screencast of Meteor:
http://www.meteor.com/screencast
Just a wild guess :)